# Sync call (blocking) from Netty 5.x handler

Tags: java, netty

I have a question about calling a blocking function in Netty (ex: a jdbc function).

From what I know, this call should not be made from the nio event loop executor because this loop must remain non-blocking to process other requests.
For current Netty version (5.0 Alpha), I can think on the following options:

1. Using a DefaultEventExecutorGroup for dispatching this blocking calls.

2. Using a java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService.

Are these options valid?
Is the second option a valid one for using safely the context?
Is another option recommended to avoid sync locks in nio event loop executors?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid, while the first ensure the correct order per Channel. So in most cases 1) is the way to go.

Comment: Ty. Can you explain: correct order per channel? I don't see the diff between the 2 approaches. 1) will use a queue for every executor for my sync tasks. But it seems I will not get the same executor for a channel (an executor obtained from my sync group executors). I will get the same nio executor for sending responses, but from what I can test, the executor used in syncCallExecutorGroup.submit() will be the next executor in my sync group. So task1 -> syncExecutor1, task2 -> syncExecutor2, both will use the same nioExecutor1 for sending responses. But the order is not mandatory resp1, resp2.